# Spring reactive streaming data from regular WebClient request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Im learning new Spring WebFlux and reactive programming.

I would like to create reactive API that streams some data to Angular client.
Part of this data I will take from another (third party) API that does not support streams.

So, as I understand I need to:

1. Create REST stream end-point.
2. Link some service to that.
3. This service will call third party API every 5 seconds using WebClient. And 
   put data to my stream. (not sure about this step)
4. That stream is going to be returned by @RestController.

How can I implement this 4 steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your remote service responds with a collection of POJOs that Jackson can deserialize as `Something.class`, you can do something like:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/streaming", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Flux<Something> streamSomething() {
  return WebClient.create()
    .get().uri("http://example.org/resource")
    .retrieve().bodyToFlux(Something.class)
    .delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
    .repeat();
}
```

Comment: Nice! Would it be performance/efficiency wise different from `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).flatMap(__ -> WebClient.create("http://localhost:8083/").get().exchange().flatMap(r -> r.bodyToMono(Hello.class)));`

Comment: @Maciej I don't know. But `repeat` operators can offer much more. And in your case, you're recreating an HTTP client for every single request.

Comment: Yes, normally I would extract WebClient creation somewhere. Thanks @Brian, I'll have a deeper look in repeat operators.