# Spring WebClient: Parse + Stream very large JSON

Tags: spring-webflux

This question is similar to [Spring reactive streaming data from regular WebClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063531/spring-reactive-streaming-data-from-regular-webclient-request) with the difference that I'm not getting JSON array immediately from my WebClient, but something like this:

This JSON object can be very large (~100MB), and thus needs to be worked on and streamed to the client, instead of parsed.  This here is the only way I seem to be able to get the semantics correct:

```
{
   "result-set":{
      "docs":[
         {
            "id":"auhcsasb1005_100000"
         },
         {
            "id":"auhcsasb1005_1000000"
         },
         {
            "id":"auhcsasb1005_1000001"
         },
         {
            "id":"auhcsasb1005_1000002"
         },
         ...
         ...
         {
            "EOF":true
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

```
WebClient.create()
  .get()
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(DontKnowWhatClass.class)
  .flatMapMany(resultSet -> Flux.fromIterable(resultSet.getDocs()))
```

BUT that means that I'm deserializing 100MB or more in memory, to then create a flux from it.  What I'm wondering is: Am I missing something crucial? Can I somehow just create a Flux from an Object like that?  I have now way to influence how the result-set object is rendered, sadly.

Comment: So, what's wrong with 100 MB?

Comment: @k-nicholas That with 20 simultaneous requests it's suddenly 2GB. It doesn't scale.

Comment: Instead of sending a single JSON have you considered using Server Sent Events so you send one entry at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine a way to reliably parse such a huge chunk of json in smaller parts. You could try to somehow convert the big chunk into smaller tokens and try to process them step by step.

But I would assume that this ending with the expected result, i.e. allow a more memory efficient parsing, is absolutely not guaranteed.

But, there are other ways to approach this problem, especially when you work reactive.

If you work in a reactive WebFlux context, you could try to use [backpressure](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-backpressure) or [rate limiting](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/ratelimiter) to make your application only parse a limited number of JSON objects at the same time. This would preserve the limited resources (RAM, CPU, JVM threads etc.) of your application.

And if the size of the objects really passes the 100MB limit, you should really consider questioning the current data model. Is this data structure and its size really suitable?

Maybe this problem cannot be solved with technical / implementation means. Maybe the current application design need to be changed.

Comment: It's more the API - a stream coming (if I remember correctly) from a solr search query.  There are solr clients, but since parsing of json and such is a no-brainer nowadays I didn't want to use it just for reading data.  In the end the API is broken - why wrap a stream of objects in a main object?  And indeed Solr offers some streaming API, too, but I'm long gone from the project where this was relevant to me... If there's interest I can dig something up.

Answer (score -1):

You can accept a `ServerWebExchange` to your controller which has a method that will take a Publisher `exchange.response.writeWith()`.

If you have a way to parse the payload in chunks you just create a Flux that emits the parts.

For example, if you don't care about the payload at all and just want to ship it as-is:

```
    @GetMapping("/api/foo/{myId}")
    fun foo(exchange: ServerWebExchange, @PathVariable myId: Long): Mono<Void> {
        val content: Flux<DataBuffer> = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("/api/up-stream/bar/$myId")
            .exchange()
            .flatMapMany { it.bodyToFlux<DataBuffer>() }

        return exchange.response.writeWith(content)
    }
```

Make sure you check the content negotiation settings to avoid something buffering you didn't expect.

Comment: the biggest problem I have is, that I DO care about the content, and I want to parse the array entries, but not the encompassing Json Object; is my assumption wrong, that plain json parsers will parse til the end of the object, and only then make further processing possible?  
The writeWith sounds like a neat thing, I find.

Comment: Then you'll need to find a way to generate a `Flux` of the values you want. JSON libs will typically parse the whole thing as it needs to in order to know if it's even well formed. 

You might have to drop to something lower level. In the code I posted you'll get 'chunks' of it in the `DataBuffer` but you might have to do some book keeping to jump from the 'network' layer to the 'application' layer akin to SAX processing from the XML days.  It seems Jackson offers such an API https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api

Comment: ah, now I remember, in the end I resorted to something similar, this was a apache solr streaming response parser, and let that output on each document event or something... but using plain json is a better idea, I find, since SolrClient is a lot more than I needed at that point in time...  Thanks for the json streaming hint!

Comment: This does not address the question presented. The original poster would want to generate a flux of the elements of the parsed JSON.